# A bug in Java XMLGregorianCalendar conversion to a Java util.Date?

Tags: java, datetime, date

I'm writing a date/time value to an XML file by reading the date from a RAP based UI as a Java Date object, and passing it as an `XMLGregorianCalendar` object to actual file writing code. The corresponding classes are auto generated and I don't have control over them. The date I entered was:

> 03-03-1933:03:03:03.

It got converted to the following string when written in the file:

> 1933-03-03T03:03:03.161+05:53

Now, when I read the date back to show it in the UI for edit, it appeared there as:

> 03-03-1933:03:03:23

Note the extra 20 seconds added to the actual seconds value.

Why is this happening? Is it some bug in the API? Any help will be much appreciated!

Relevant code:

1) Converting to `XMLGregorianCalendar`from `Date`:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(); 
calendar.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
XMLGregorianCalendar date2;
date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);

// pass 'date2' to file writing code
```

2) Converting to `Date` from `XMLGregorianCalendar`:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar cal = getDateFromFile(); // XML date read from file
Date date = cal.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();

// show Date object in UI, dateCtrl and timeCtrl are SWT DateTime objects

GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();  
calendar.setTime( date );

dateCtrl.setDate( calendar.get( GregorianCalendar.YEAR ),
    calendar.get( GregorianCalendar.MONTH ),
    calendar.get( GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH ) );

timeCtrl.setTime( calendar.get( GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ),
    calendar.get( GregorianCalendar.MINUTE ),
    calendar.get( GregorianCalendar.SECOND) );
```

Comment: There's something strange going on in the second line of step 1: converting your `Date` to a `GegorianCalendar` appears to give it a very strange time zone: `+05:53`. Also strange is that it has an offset of 161 milliseconds. Could you provide code showing how you created `date`? On my machine, `date2` results in `1933-03-03T03:03:03.000+01:00` (which is correct for my Amsterdam time zone).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I use two SWT DateTime objects. One to get the date and the other to get the time. Here's the relevant code:                                                                 int day = dateCtrl.getDay();
  int month = dateCtrl.getMonth();
  int year = dateCtrl.getYear();
  
  int hrs = timeCtrl.getHours();
  int mins = timeCtrl.getMinutes();
  int seconds = timeCtrl.getSeconds();
  
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.set(year, month, day, hrs, mins, seconds);
  Date date = calendar.getTime();

Comment: Can this be related to India's time zone is UTC+05:30, but `XMLGregorianCalendar::getTimezone()` returns `int` (for number of hours of UTC offset)?  This appears to be a weakness of the type.  Also of interest would be Nepal (UTC+05:45) and Afghanistan (UTC+04:30).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to about 1968 there were all sorts of weird offsets, especially in less-developed parts of the world.  You don't say what locale you're using, but if it's in India, there was once something called Howra Mean Time that had that offset.  I don't know if it was in effect in 1933 however.  You will likely have to download the [tz database](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm) for your locale and check the configuration for that date.

EDIT: To verify exactly what is happening, try:

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
TimeZone tz = c.getTimeZone();
System.out.println(tz);

int tzo = tz.getOffset(date.getTime());
System.out.println(
      tzo/3600000 + ":" + 
      (tzo/60000)%60 + ":" + 
      (tzo/1000)%60 + "." + 
      tzo%1000);
```

This will tell you what the system thinks the current timezone is, and the timezone offset in effect on the problematic date in 1933.  When I run this in my system I get:

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Chicago",offset=-21600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Chicago,offset=-21600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
-6:0:0.0
```

HOWEVER, if I change one line:

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
```

I then get:

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="IST",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null]
5:53:20.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm in India but I'm using 'en_US' as the locale.

Comment: Locale and time zone are unrelated, which the answer doesn’t make clear. So en_US locale isn’t relevant. If you are using Asia/Kolkata time zone, that would seem to be part of the explanation.