# Timezone inconsistencies on converting XMLGregorianCalendar to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, time, timezone, xmlgregoriancalendar

So I have an XML Soap response with date / time fields, which are represented as follows:

```
<BusStopTime>
    <BusStopId>1023</BusStopId>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <PassingTime>1899-12-30T07:20:00</PassingTime>
</BusStopTime>
```

I'm not interested in the date (as this is some legacy representation which I don't have control over) but the time. The field is transformed to `XMLGregorianCalendar` by the WS tooling and I'm aiming to do the conversion.

```
var date = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
    .newXMLGregorianCalendar("1899-12-30T07:20:00")
    .toGregorianCalendar().toInstant()
```

Converting to `LocalDateTime` is siLocalimple. I'm setting TimeZone explicitly to avoid locality confuction

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date, ZoneId.of("Europe/Warsaw"))
```

which results in **1899-12-30T07:44**

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date, ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"))
```

gives me a different output **1899-12-30T07:20**

When dates start in modern days (after 1900 and after) - everything works fine. So the question is: what exactly happened between Berlin and Warsaw on the turn of XIX century? Or put it more clearly - why the change in the time is so *weird*?

I'm running is on both JDK8 and JDK11 (observing the same behavior)

```
{ ~ }  » java -version                                                                                                                                              
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)

java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What is your concern?

Comment: Warzaw was at offset +01:24 from GMT all the time up to 1915 ([source](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/poland/warsaw)). Berlin at +01:00 from 1894 to 1915 ([source](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin)). It seems this would be part of the explanation. But nothing special happened at the turn of the century in either place, so it doesn’t fully explain.

Comment: When I run your code, I get exactly the same difference for dates after 1900. For example `1914-12-30T07:20:00` too becomes 7:44 in Warsaw and 7:20 in Berlin.

Comment: When I try to create an `XMLGregorianCalendar` from you example string, `1899-12-30T07:20:00`, in different time zones, I do get a couple of surprising results, though. If you can get the string out of the XML, use `LocalDateTime.parse("1899-12-30T07:20:00")` for a predictable result.

Comment: Thank you Ole! I was thinking about timezones but couldn't find any reference. Your sources are great. I didn't have problems with conversion `(LocalDateTime.parse(xmllGregoriaCalendar.toXmlFormat())` - worked like a charm. But was curious about the algorithm and rules themselves. If you've added it as an answer I would've had happily accept it

Comment: Somehow related: [A bug in Java XMLGregorianCalendar conversion to a Java util.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282650/a-bug-in-java-xmlgregoriancalendar-conversion-to-a-java-util-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### LocalDateTime.parse()

If you can get the string out of the XML without too much trouble, for a predictable result use

```
    LocalDateTime.parse("1899-12-30T07:20:00")
```

**Edit:** Without direct access to the string I suggest that the solution is to set an offset from GMT/UTC on your `XMLGregorianCalendar` to avoid any dependency on the JVM’s default time zone:

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar("1899-12-30T07:20:00");
    xgc.setTimezone(0);
    LocalTime time = xgc.toGregorianCalendar()
            .toZonedDateTime()
            .toLocalTime();
    System.out.println(time);
```

Since the so-called “timezone” of an `XMLGregorianCalendar` is really nothing but a fixed offset, it doesn’t matter which value we set. The output from this snippet consistently is:

> 07:20

I have tested with nine different default time zones including Europe/Warsaw.

Since you said you were only interested in the time of day, not the date, I have converted to `LocalTime`. If you want a `LocalDateTime` as in your question, just use `toLocalDateTime` instead of `toLocalTime`,

Alternatively, this was your easy solution from your comment:

```
    LocalDateTime.parse(xmllGregoriaCalendar.toXMLFormat​())
```

`toXMLFormat​()` recreates the string from the XML that the `XMLGregorianCalendar` object was created from (the docs guarantee that you get the same string back). So this way too evades all time zone problems.

### Edit: disagreement between old and new classes

It seems to me that the heart of the problem lies in the old and outdated `TimeZone` class and the modern `ZoneId` class not agreeing about historic offsets from GMT/UTC.

I did a couple of experiments. Let’s first try the time zone that seems to work correctly, Berlin. Berlin was at offset +01:00 from 1894 to 1915. Java knows that:

```
    LocalDate baseDate = LocalDate.of(1899, Month.DECEMBER, 30);

    ZoneId berlin = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
    TimeZone tzb = TimeZone.getTimeZone(berlin);
    GregorianCalendar gcb = new GregorianCalendar(tzb);
    gcb.set(1899, Calendar.DECEMBER, 30);
    ZonedDateTime zdtb = baseDate.atStartOfDay(berlin);
    System.out.println("" + berlin + ' ' + tzb.getOffset(gcb.getTimeInMillis())
            + ' ' + berlin.getRules().getOffset(zdtb.toInstant())
            + ' ' + berlin.getRules().getOffset(zdtb.toInstant()).getTotalSeconds());
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Europe/Berlin 3600000 +01:00 3600

The offset for 30 December 1899 is given correctly as +01:00. The `TimeZone` class says 3 600 000 milliseconds, `ZoneId` says 3600 seconds, so they agree.

The trouble is with Warsaw. Warsaw was at GMT offset +01:24 all the time up to 1915. Let’s see if Java can find out:

```
    ZoneId warsaw = ZoneId.of("Europe/Warsaw");
    TimeZone tzw = TimeZone.getTimeZone(warsaw);
    GregorianCalendar gcw = new GregorianCalendar(tzw);
    gcw.set(1899, Calendar.DECEMBER, 30);
    ZonedDateTime zdtw = baseDate.atStartOfDay(warsaw);
    System.out.println("" + warsaw + ' ' + tzw.getOffset(gcw.getTimeInMillis())
            + ' ' + warsaw.getRules().getOffset(zdtw.toInstant())
            + ' ' + warsaw.getRules().getOffset(zdtw.toInstant()).getTotalSeconds());
```

> Europe/Warsaw 3600000 +01:24 5040

`ZoneId` correctly says +01:24 or 5040 seconds, but here `TimeZone` says 3 600 000 milliseconds, the same as in the Berlin case. This is incorrect.

The old `GregorianCalendar` class relies on the old `TimeZone` class and therefore produces wrong results when using Europe/Warsaw time zone (either explicitly or as default). In particular you get the wrong `Instant` from `Calendar.toInstant()`. And exactly because `LocalDateTime.ofInstant` uses a modern `ZoneId`, the error is carried on into your `LocalDateTime`.

Also from Europe/Dublin, Europe/Paris, Europe/Moscow and Asia/Kolkata time zones I get contradictory results.

I have run my snippets on Java 1.8.0_131, Java 9.0.4 and Java 11. The results were the same on all versions.

### Links

- [Documentation of `DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar-java.lang.String-)
- [Time Zone in Berlin, Germany on timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin)
- [Time Zone in Warsaw, Poland (Warszawa) on timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/poland/warsaw)

Comment: I was thinking about a bug as well but `GregorianCalendar` just holds timezone information correctly. Converting `GregorianCalendar` to Instance results in a proper UTC date. The moment things get weird is when timezones (`ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date, ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))`) are applied. The result is coherent with the timezone spec in links you've provided (timezone seems to be calculated according to a year- which seem legit) so at this moment I'm more inclined towards my initial lack of understanding of timezones than an actual bug.